# Slow system call and signals

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have read this subject:
[Relationship slow system call with signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226305/relationship-slow-system-call-with-signal)

and everything isn't clear for me. Especially I don't understand this part of answer because I don't see a problem with included source code.
Please explain me.
Thanks in advance.

> Anyway, back to the question. If you're wondering why the read doesn't
>   fail with EINTR the answer is SA_RESTART. On most Unix systems a few
>   system calls are automatically restarted in the event of a signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP was expecting the `read` call to return an error code because it was interrupted by a signal.  In the case of the `read` system call, the OS automatically restarts this system call in the event of a signal, so no error was returned.

Comment: Note also, however, that the referenced answer *is* a little off.  The `SA_RESTART` flag accepted by `sigaction()` is not directly relevant to `signal()`.  POSIX specifies that when a signal handler set via `signal()` returns (in the relevant case) "the program shall resume execution at the point it was interrupted".  That's similar, but not identical, to the behavior required when the `SA_RESTART` flag is specified to `sigaction()`.  In practice, however, I don't know whether implementations actually treat the two differently.